# Orthonormal basis for a subspace of a Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, inner-products

On a Hilbert space $H$ with an orthonormal basis $(e_j)_{j \ge 1}$, define $E$ to be spanned by $e_1 + e_2, e_3 + e_4, $ and $e_2 + e_3$.

What's an orthonormal basis for $E$?

I have no idea where to begin. Usually we are given some vectors, and then I'd apply Gram-Schmidt, but what now?

Comment: You are given three vectors that span $E$. How is this any different from usual?

Comment: How is this any different than usual? Well, for starters, the vectors aren't explicitly given which rules out any calculations with them?

Comment: You're terminology is off.  By definition, any element of a vector space is a "vector".  What you would *like* to work with is a vertical array of numbers, which is generally called a "column vector" or an "element of $\Bbb R^n$".

Comment: Why would I like to work with a vertical array or a "column vector"?  If $E$ was spanned by $1, x$ and $x^2$, I could deduce that these are linearly independent, and then I would apply Gram-Schmidt to $1$, $x$ and $x^2$, giving an ONB of $1, x - 1$ and $x^2 - 2x - 2/3$. This is what I am used to, and the lack of these explicit definitions is what's confusing me.

Comment: Oh, I see where you're coming from.  The key here is that orthonormality is all you need.

Comment: In particular, once we've established an orthonormal basis, the inner product is completely defined.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** We don't lose any information if we represent these vectors as column vectors.  In particular, set
$$
e_1 = \pmatrix{1\\0\\0\\0}, \dots, e_4 = \pmatrix{0\\0\\0\\1}
$$
Now, apply Gram Schmidt.

---

Note, however, that we don't necessarily need coordinate vectors to apply Gram-Schmidt.  In particular, we begin the the vectors
$$
v_1 = e_1 + e_2\\
v_2 = e_3 + e_4\\
v_3 = e_2 + e_3
$$
We want to find an orthonormal basis $u_1,u_2,u_3$ of the span.  We begin by saying
$$
u_1 = \frac{1}{\|v_1\|}v_1 = \frac 1{\sqrt{\langle e_1 + e_2, e_1 + e_2 \rangle}}(e_1 + e_2)
$$
Note, however, that
$$
\langle e_1 + e_2, e_1 + e_2 \rangle = 
\langle e_1, e_1 \rangle + 
\langle e_2, e_1 \rangle + 
\langle e_1, e_2 \rangle + 
\langle e_2, e_2 \rangle =\\
1 + 0 + 0 + 1 = 2
$$
so, we have
$$
v_1 = \frac 1{\sqrt 2} e_1 + \frac 1{\sqrt 2} e_2
$$
perhaps you can take it from there.

Comment: I don't understand what's going on here. We are talking about some Hilbert space which could be anything, so where did the vectors come from?

Comment: They're [coordinate vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_vector) for elements of the span of $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$.

Comment: Also, see my latest edit.